# Pax-Exam How to install bundles to container

Tags: junit, osgi, pax-exam

How to install bundles to the Pax-Exam container from the local m2 repository?..

I was able to install from giving a file URL.

```
@Configuration
public Option[] config() {

    return options(
                  bundle("file:///home/sample/Desktop/sample.jar"),
                  junitBundles()
    );
```

But thats not scalable solution. So how can I tell the Pax-Exam to install bundles from the local m2 repository?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pax exam has a confiuration option mavenBundle that will help with this. It also supports to use the version from the pom. So you do not need it in the java source.

[See Configuration using Maven Plugin](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxexam/Configuration+using+Maven+Plugin)

Comment: It will search the local repo first.

Comment: Thanks Christian for the clarification and the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Sorry for the noise.

bundle("mvn:org.sample.bundle/bundle-id/version")

https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxurl/Mvn+Protocol#MvnProtocol-local